# How to get currently running applications in windows 8 programmatically?

Tags: c#, windows-8

I want to create an app for Listing currently running applications in windows 8 using vsExpress 2012 (Windows store C#)

I tried to get using `System.Diagnostics.Process`, but in windows 8 its not supporting "Process" class,

if anybody knows, share it .

Comment: Is this a 'modern' app or a 'desktop' app?

Answer (score 1):

Process is available with Windows 8, but not with Windows RT. Are you developing a store application (Windows RT)? If so, there's no way to get the information you want (security!).

Answer (score 0):

Is there is a way by using System.Threading.task (or) Anyother way is there to get Currently running applications list in windows 8 (windows store apps)