# How can I list all opened apps including metro ones, in C#?

Tags: c#, windows-8, process

I want to create an incremental switcher between open apps and I need to include metro ones.
The view that I want to show is something like what it is present in TaskManager of Windows 8 in the "Fewer Details View".

[image]

There you could see how metro ones are shown side by side with the desktop apps. 
I've tried with the Process.GetProcess() method but without success till now.

Comment: Similar One [Stack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112812/how-to-get-currently-running-applications-in-windows-8-programmatically)

Comment: Even better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207487/getting-a-list-of-all-applications-in-c-sharp. Just remember that a `Process` object has the `MainWindowTitle`, which is what you're aiming for.